# Open ODBC connection from data source Ms Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, datasource, ado, dao

I am trying to connect to an ODBC data source that is properly setup and when i run the test connection it works. BUt when migrating my code from DAO to ADO the code sample below gives me an error: `cannot connect to mysql server on localhot (10061)`

Here is the sample code:

```
Dim conODBC As New ADODB.Connection
      Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
      conODBC.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};dsn=SomeDataSource;UID=SomeUserID;"
```

any ideas what could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: Maybe try specifying the Server and Database instead of using a DSN? I found this example: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-programming-vb-ado.html. Also, if that isn't a good option, did you try linking the table(s) of interest?

Comment: Interesting. Please show the DAO code that does work.